# Getting specific line inside CSV file via powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a CSV file like below. I want to only fetch info@contoso.com line like below.

My CSV file:

```
Report Refresh Date,User Principal Name,Display Name,Is Deleted,Deleted Date,Last Activity Date,Send Count,Receive Count,Read Count,Meeting Created Count,Meeting Interacted Count,Assigned Products,Report Period
2022-10-05,user01@contoso.com,User01,False,,2022-10-05,0,0,0,0,0,POWER BI (FREE)+DYNAMICS 365 CUSTOMER SERVICE ENTERPRISE+MICROSOFT VIVA INSIGHTS+OFFICE 365 E3+ENTERPRISE MOBILITY + SECURITY E3,30
2022-10-05,info@contoso.com,info,False,,2022-10-05,0,0,0,0,0,POWER BI (FREE)+DYNAMICS 365 CUSTOMER SERVICE ENTERPRISE+MICROSOFT VIVA INSIGHTS+OFFICE 365 E3+ENTERPRISE MOBILITY + SECURITY E3,30
2022-10-05,user02@contoso.com,user02,False,,2022-10-05,0,0,0,0,0,POWER BI (FREE)+DYNAMICS 365 CUSTOMER SERVICE ENTERPRISE+MICROSOFT VIVA INSIGHTS+OFFICE 365 E3+ENTERPRISE MOBILITY + SECURITY E3,30
```

My desired output:

```
Report Refresh Date,User Principal Name,Display Name,Is Deleted,Deleted Date,Last Activity Date,Send Count,Receive Count,Read Count,Meeting Created Count,Meeting Interacted Count,Assigned Products,Report Period
2022-10-05,info@contoso.com,info,False,,2022-10-05,0,0,0,0,0,POWER BI (FREE)+DYNAMICS 365 CUSTOMER SERVICE ENTERPRISE+MICROSOFT VIVA INSIGHTS+OFFICE 365 E3+ENTERPRISE MOBILITY + SECURITY E3,30
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#Load csv
$csv = import-csv [path]

#Get entry where User Principal Name eq info@contoso.com
$entry = $csv | ?{$_.'User Principal Name' -eq 'info@contoso.com'}
```

The variable $entry contains the related object.

If you need a csv output on the screen:

```
$entry | convertto-csv
```

If you need the csv output as file

```
$entry | export-csv [path]
```

Comment: You can actually fold these together as `$entries = Import-CSV $filepath | Where-Object {$_.'User Principal Name' -eq 'info@contoso.com'}`

Comment: It should be noted that `Import-CSV` creates `PSCustomObject`s in memory where the property names match the titles of the columns in the CSV. If you want to generate a CSV file from the results, you'd need to use the `Export-CSV` cmdlet, either as `$entries | Export-CSV -Path $newfile` or as `Export-CSV -Path $NewFile -InputObject $entries`.

Comment: @Jeff Zeitlin - sure you can do it on one line. I prefer it this way as it is more readable from my point ov view, why do you mention this - I don't see any advantage?! yes I know what import-csv does...

Comment: I only mention it because the querent appeared to be wanting a CSV as the output. There's nothing _wrong_ about what you did; it's ultimately a stylistic choice.

Comment: @Jeff Zeitlin, ok right added the convert-csv to the answer....

Answer (score 0):

how about this?

```
# define path to CSV
$CSV = "C:\a.csv"

# import CSV Contents
$CSVContent = Import-Csv $CSV

# go through each entry in the CSV file
foreach ($Entry in $CSVContent){

    # if the entry matches a certain criteria
    If ($Entry."User Principal Name" -eq "info@contoso.com"){

        # output that entry to console
        Write-Output $Entry

    }

}
```

Comment: This will not give the output in the format that the querent appears to desire, though it _will_ correctly select the desired entries.

Answer (score 0):

```
Import-Csv ./input.csv |
 Where-Object 'User Principal Name' -eq 'info@contoso.com' |
 ConvertTo-Csv
```

Answer (score 0):

It’s actually possible to do this a one-liner in PowerShell. For the purposes of the exercise, `$contoso` is the original file, and `$infocontoso` is the file that will contain only the desired records.

```
Import-CSV -Path $Contoso | Where-Object {$_.'User Principal Name' -eq 'info@contoso.com'} | Export-CSV -Path $infocontoso
```